# How to register for ADM 201 Winter 17

Tags: certification, adm201

I am not able to find how to register for ADM 201 winter 2017. On the Webassessor site, It is only showing the "Salesforce Certified Administrator SU17" exam.

Can someone please help me to register to the ADM 201 winter 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Salesforce ADM201 certification is now called 'Salesforce Certified Administrator SU17'.

SU17 stands for the latest release being Summer 17'

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Chrish, If i take ADM 201 SU17, how long will it be valid ?

Comment: @max your certification will remain valid as long as you take the resits which happen every release usually 3 times a year, more information here on it http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Maintaining-Your-Salesforce-Credential